# Give an example of fields $k\subseteq K\subseteq L $, and $l\subseteq L$, for which $l/k$ and $L/K$ are algebraic, $k$ is algebraically closed

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, galois-extensions

**Give an example of fields $k\subseteq K\subseteq L $, and $l\subseteq L$, for which $l/k$ and $L/K$ are algebraic, $k$ is algebraically closed in $K$, and $lK = L$, but $l$ is not algebraically closed in $L$.**

This question has already been posted here [$k$ is algebraically closed in $K$, and $lK=L$ , but $l$ is not algebraically closed in $L$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2114331/k-is-algebraically-closed-in-k-and-lk-l-but-l-is-not-algebraically-cl), but has not yet had an answer, the truth is that I can not find such an example, could someone please help me? Thank you very much.

Comment: @reuns what else can I say about the problem?

Comment: @reuns 
I have thought about taking $k =\mathbb{Q}, K =\mathbb{C} = L $ but I do not know how to choose $l$ so that the other is true, could you help me with this please?